# Binding to a List property of a Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following Model

```
public class FooContainer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Example Controller

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(){
        return View(new FooContainer());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FooContainer model){
        //Do stuff with the model
    }
}
```

I want to create a view which enables the user to CRUD Foos.

**Existing Research**

I have read the following:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

along with the following SO articles
[MVC4 Allowing Users to Edit List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648035/mvc4-allowing-users-to-edit-list-items) 
[MVC4 bind model to ICollection or List in partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750946/mvc4-bind-model-to-icollection-or-list-in-partial)

So i know how to pass an IEnumerable<> back and forth, the problem is that i want to pass some container, with other attributes *including* an IEnumerable<>

**Requirement** 
I want to be able to bind to this complex model so that it is passed completely and in its entirety to the controller. Assume that the controller does nothing but render the view and receive the FooController model on post. Additionally i would like any relevant articles or references to View syntax required to enable this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, please, describe of one method in FooController.

Comment: Maybe it can help: google by 'mvc4 custom binders'

Comment: I'm looking into MVC4 Custom Binders now... they look kinda cool!

Comment: If that doesn't help, write here in comments again.

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom model binder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started.

Your Models:

```
public class FooContainer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Your Controller Actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = new FooContainer();
    return View("Foo", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(FooContainer model)
{
    ViewBag.Test = m.Foos[1].Name;
    return View("Foo", model);
}
```

Your View:

```
@model DriveAway.Web.Models.FooContainer

@using(Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID)</p>
    <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</p>   

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foos[i].Name)</p>
        <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foos[i].Description)</p>
    }

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}

@ViewBag.Test
```

What happens here is when you press submit, the iList will be sent to your HttpPost Foo() action and there you can do whatever you want with it. In my example, it'll show whatever was input into the second Name text box. You can obviously loop through each value and check if filled out etc. e.g.

```
foreach (var f in m.Foos)
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(f.Description))
       addToDB(f); // some method to add to to a database
```

In the view i used a `for loop` with a limit of 5. But this is obviously up to you.

Comment: Hi Rudeovski, I am not sure if this is what i am after, i will have a look. I'm not sure how this will pass back the whole container, it looks like it will pass back an IEnumerable<Foo> to the controller (which i can get working already). I want to pass the complex model, not just a list.

Comment: It'll pass the whole FooContainer back. I've added in the other 2 properties into the View. So on submit, it'll pass in ID and Name from FooContainer, and the list of Foos.